# Deleting files on a drive with ?.?

Tags: cmd.exe, wildcards

In the command line you can use the `*.*` pattern to delete all the files on a specified drive, and with the `*` being a wildcard wouldn't `?.?` do the same?

I would try it on my own PC, but in the event it does work I wouldn't be a happy camper.

Comment: Check this thread on DosTips. https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6207#p39420

Answer (score 1):

The `?.?` pattern would only match files or folders which consist on one character, a dot and another character. Or a single character. Or a single character followed by a dot.

For example, it would match `1.1` or `x.Z`, `1` and `1.`, but not `11` `111` or `1.jpg`.

Why it has that feature of "ignoring" the extension part of the pattern is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Source [DEL](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html)

> Delete one or more files.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> DEL [options] [/A:file_attributes] files_to_delete
>
> **Key**
>
> files_to_delete : This may be a filename, a list of files or a
> Wildcard
>
> ...
>
> **Wildcards**:
>
> These can be combined with part of a filename
>
> *  Match any characters
>
> ?  Match any ONE character

`del *.*` will delete all files in the current directory

`del ?.?` will delete all files with one character in the file name and/or one character in the file extension (for example files like "a.a", "a." or ".a")

See also [MS-DOS and Windows Wildcard Characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.